# Why elements are removed after iframe

Tags: html, iframe

I have just noticed my element is not rendered in the browser after an iframe element.
Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>  
    <div class="xpto">
        <iframe id="myIframe"  src="http://www.google.com/custom?q=&btnG=Search" height="500px" width="100%"/>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        something
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bonomi/12a0xr0a/)

Does anyone knows why?

Is I remove the iframe everything works fine!

Comment: can you add the relevant css please?

Comment: @AmanuelNega Doesn't seem like a css problem since it uncludes an offsite source.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `</iframe>` instead of ending the element tag within itself which is `<tag />`

```html
<div class="xpto">
    <iframe id="myIframe"  src="http://www.google.com/custom?q=&btnG=Search" height="500px" width="100%"></iframe>
 </div>
 <div class="footer">
  something
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you close the `<iframe>` tag it will show the footer

```
<iframe id="myIframe"  src="http://www.google.com/custom?q=&btnG=Search" height="500px" width="100%">
</iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should close iframe by  tag.

Here is working fiddle ,

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/12a0xr0a/2/)

```
<iframe id="myIframe"  src="http://www.google.com/custom?q=&btnG=Search" height="500px" width="100%"></iframe>
```